# How to Pair or Get pairing request from Omron BP monitor (HEM - 7600T model) using Core Bluetooth to my iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, pairing

I am trying to understand how to pair/bond or get pairing request from Omron BP monitor device to my iOS application but I couldn't get any codes or solution for the same.

I see there are easy way for android application to integrate these kinds of BLE devices using third party SDK (https://github.com/weliem/blessed-android). Is there something similar like in iOS or how to proceed working on the same to get pairing request and get values from the device to my app.

I have used other devices like oximeter or thermi integration which doesn't require any paring request. All these devices integration are handled by getting from Core Bluetooth methods but for device like omron its not happening.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please try to connect to the device using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to test the connection. It might well be that Omron uses a custom set of services and characteristics to force you to use their app.

Comment: When you need to pair, you usually need to read a protected characteristic that will trigger a pairing, and will make it readable afterward.

Comment: @VigneshKrish Did you manage to solve it? I see Omron doesn't expose the standard BP Service i.e. 0x1810 but exposes it's own Custom service. Can you help if you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

there is an open source framework Bluejay you can checkout. I have not tried it but it has the same type of resources you're looking for, Link:- https://github.com/steamclock/bluejay/tree/master .